# Hiding select text with js

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, hide

I have a select option like below. The values are created dynamically. Is there a way to hide the prices using js/jquery?

Keep in mind i can't access the text, so i can't wrap price in a span and set display:none

```
<label for="input_1_33">Condition</label>
<select tabindex="2" name="input_33">
<option value="Please Select|" price="">Please Select</option>
<option value="Poor|-5" price="-£ 5.00">Poor -£ 5.00</option>
<option value="Average|0" price="">Average</option>
<option value="Good|5" price="+£ 5.00">Good +£ 5.00</option>
<option value="Excellent|10" price="+£ 10.00">Excellent +£ 10.00</option>
</select>
```

So it looks like this:

```
<label for="input_1_33">Condition</label>
<select tabindex="2" name="input_33">
<option value="Please Select|" price="">Please Select</option>
<option value="Poor|-5" price="-£ 5.00">Poor</option>
<option value="Average|0" price="">Average</option>
<option value="Good|5" price="+£ 5.00">Good</option>
<option value="Excellent|10" price="+£ 10.00">Excellent</option>
</select>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "hide"? Do you mean to hide them if someone does view source on the code?

Comment: Why do you want to do it through js? Why not render the way you want from server side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an ultra-concise way to do what you need: **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sj9eB/)**

jQuery:

```
$('select[name="input_33"] option:gt(0)').each(function(){
    $(this).text( ($(this).text().split(' ')[0]) );
});
```

Comment: This worked for me with a slight tweek. But thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Assign an ID to the Select and then the following in a Script block:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#input_33").each(function () {
            $('option', this).each(function () {
                var option = this;
                var space = option.text.indexOf(" ");
                if (space > -1) {
                    option.text = option.text.substring(0,space);
                }

            })

        });
    });
</script>
```

EDIT: As you can see what I do is to find the space in each option item, and then cut the string where it find the space. It will make "Please Select" read "Please" but you get the drift.

Good luck!

Comment: It's not kosher. It's work only if option has one-word text before the price.

Comment: The plan is not to do his Homework/Work for him, but that he gets the idea IMHO.